При клике на label у input:color сбрасывается выделение текста
Всем привет, есть input type:color, есть label для него, есть блок с текстом, при клике на сам input выделение текста не сбрасывается, при клике на label сбрасывается, как оставить выделение?
<div class="text-editor-modal__colorBlock">
      <label class="material-icons-outlined">{{iconColorText | iconName}}</label>
      <input id="color" type="color" (input)="onColorInput()" #inputColorEl
             class="text-editor-modal__inputColor">
    </div>      
  <div id="content" class="text-editor-modal__content" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
    {{text}}
  </div>


